# Getting values from child in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, children

I have activity with RecyclerView. RecyclerView row layout code is bellow. In row layout I have editTexts. When user fill the edittexts I want get values from these edittext in RecyclerView. I can not get correct values. It looks like adapter return bad values or I don't know where is problem. Any idea what I do bad?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="5"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exercise_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ab000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_repeats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/float_label"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_weight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/float_label"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class SeriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeriesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Series> series = null;
private Context context = null;


public SeriesAdapter(ArrayList<Series> series, Context context) {
    this.series = series;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public SeriesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.series_scr_row, parent, false);
    SeriesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view, new SeriesAdapter.ViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {
        @Override
        public void onRowClick(View caller, int position) {
            long id = series.get(position).idSeries;
            doAction(id);
        }
    }, new ViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicksLong() {
        @Override
        public void onRowClickLong(View caller, int position) {
            long id = series.get(position).idSeries;
            doActionLong(id);
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.exercise_name.setText(++position + context.getResources().getString(R.string.series_label));
    holder.et_repeats.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable ss) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return series.get(position).idSeries;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return series.size();
}

private void doAction(long id) {
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("id", id);
    startMyActivity(context, SeriesActivity.class, hashMap, false);
}

private void doActionLong(long id) {
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public TextView exercise_name;
    public EditText et_repeats;
    public EditText et_weight;
    public IMyViewHolderClicks mListener;
    public IMyViewHolderClicksLong mListenerLong;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView, IMyViewHolderClicks listener, IMyViewHolderClicksLong listenerLong) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        mListener = listener;
        mListenerLong = listenerLong;
        exercise_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name);
        et_repeats = (EditText) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.et_repeats);
        et_weight = (EditText) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onRowClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        mListenerLong.onRowClickLong(v, getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    public interface IMyViewHolderClicks {
        public void onRowClick(View caller, int position);
    }

    public interface IMyViewHolderClicksLong {
        public void onRowClickLong(View caller, int position);
    }
}
```

}

In Activity I try get values like:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < rv_series_list.getAdapter().getItemCount(); i++) {
            CardView cardView = (CardView) rv_series_list.getChildAt(i);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) cardView.getChildAt(0);

            EditText etWeight = (EditText)linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
            EditText etRepeat = (EditText)linearLayout.getChildAt(2);

            db.addRecord( new Records(-1,++i,
                    Integer.parseInt(etWeight.getText().toString()) ,
                    Integer.parseInt(etRepeat.getText().toString()), idOfExercise, -1));
        }
```

Comment: Play around with the RecyclerView and look for patterns in the data. If you notice anything, post it and comment here so the StackOverflow community can better identify and remedy the issue.